# Change PyroCMS's Admin access url

Tags: security, routes, admin, backend, pyrocms

i want to change the url of the pyrocms backend for security reasons. I tried to change it in the routes.php but all I get is

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pyro2/system/cms/libraries/MX/Modules.php on line 92
```

And this is how my routes.php looks like:

```
$route['3741/help/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)']        = 'admin/help/$1';
$route['3741/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(:any)']      = '$1/admin/$2';
$route['3741/(login|logout)']               = 'admin/$1';
$route['3741/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)']            = '$1/admin/index';
```

Any idea?

Comment: What version of Pyro are you running?

Answer (score 0):

"Security through obscurity is not security. If PyroCMS Admin Panel's were so easy to crack then we'd be having a bad day whatever you renamed it to." -Phil Sturgeon

Comment: well that's a lame excuse, if so why isnt there a default admin username? because it would be easier to brute force. its the same for the admin url. by that a hacker knows instantly which cms u run and just looks up the issues on github. too easy man :D

Comment: There are easier ways to find out what CMS a website is using then guessing the admin url.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025415/how-can-i-determine-what-cms-a-website-is-using